# Variable scope python3

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, scope

I have

```
def func1(var):
    if var == 0:
       return
    else
       var = var - 1
       func1(var)

PROPOSAL = 1

def func2():
  func1(PROPOSAL)
  print(PROPOSAL)
```

In the recursive calls in `func1`, will the variable `PROPOSAL` be decremented, meaning the `print` statement will print `0`?

Edit: I should've asked, why doesn't it do this?

Comment: So what happened when you tried this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the `PROPOSAL` global variable will not be decremented by your code. This isn't really because of scope, but because of how Python passes arguments.

When you call a function that takes an argument, the value of the argument you pass is bound to a parameter name, just like an assignment to a variable. If the value is mutable, an in-place modification through one name will be visible through the other name, but if the variable is immutable (as `int`s are in Python), you'll never see a change to one variable effect another.

Here's an example that shows functions and regular assignment working the same way:

```
x = 1

y = x   # binds the y to the same value as x
y += 1  # modify y (which will rebind it, since integers are immutable)
print(x, y) # prints "1 2"

def func(z): # z is a local variable in func
    z += 1 
    print(x, z)
func(x) # also prints "1 2", for exactly the same reasons as the code above

X = [1]

Y = X  # again, binds Y to the same list as X
Y.append(2)  # this time, we modify the list in place (without rebinding)

print(X, Y)  # prints "[1, 2] [1, 2]", since both names still refer to the same list

def FUNC(Z):
    Z.append(3):
    print(X, Z)
FUNC(X)  # prints "[1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]"
```

Of course, rebinding a variable that referred to a mutable value will also cause the change not to be reflected in other references to the original value. For instance, you replaced the `append()` calls in the second part of the code with `Y = Y + [2]` and `Z = Z + [3]`, the original `X` list would not be changed, since those assignment statements rebind `Y` and `Z` rather than modifying the original values in place.

The "augmented assignment" operators like `+=`, `-=`, and `*=` are a bit tricky. They will first try to do an in-place modification if the value on the left side supports it (and many mutable types do). If the value doesn't support in-place modification of that kind (for instance, because it's an immutable object, or because the specific operator is not allowed), it will fall back on using the regular `+` operator to create a new value instead (if that fails too it will raise an exception).

Answer (score 0):

`func1(PROPOSAL)` will return NONE and it won't affect the global `PROPOSAL` variable because you don't assign that return value to `PROPOSAL`.

`func2()` just calls func1() and then prints the `PROPOSAL` variable that wasn't changed it that scope just in `func1(PROPOSAL)`